# How can I stretch one line of flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I will be referring to this example: http://codepen.io/KenPowers/pen/CwoKc?editors=110

My desired result is to (when the screen width is at least 800px) stretch out the middle "row" so that the header is at the top and the footer is at the bottom. I would like to do this without adding any HTML markup.

Currently, the example renders as such:

[image: Render 1]

Adding the following code:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Results in the following:

[image: Render 2]

Finally, setting the `max-height` of `footer` and `header` to something like `50px` results in the following:

[image: Render 3]

How can I make it so the middle line stretches to fill all space on the page? I feel like I've tried all possible combinations of `align-content`, `align-items`, and `align-self` but to no avail.

Comment: row wrap is not avalaible in FF yet :( , maybe with aside included in article, it is easier to work from : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bwtgk

Comment: Row wrap was added in FF28: http://i.imgur.com/laI6IS1.png

Comment: right, just need an update i guess :) seen it here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=939901

Comment: You may need to add a another flex-box wrapper around the article and asides.

Looks like you are trying to achieve the "Holy Grail".  See this article, [Solved by Flexbox - Holy Grail Layout](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/)

Also check out [W3.org - CSS Flexible Box Layout Module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#order-accessibility)

Comment: Yes, it is the holy grail, and I've seen it [done with flexbox](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/), but I would prefer no wrappers if at all possible.

Comment: I absolutely agree with @GCyrillus , the way to solve this is to set the asides included in article. No extra wrappers, just change a little bit the HTML

Answer (score 0):

I had a solution I think & hope it helps to you.

I utilized [css3 reset from HTML5 doctor](http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/html5-doctor-css-reset-stylesheet/) (only must part), viewport-height unit `vh` as height unit and Equal Height Columns with Cross-Browser CSS.

Equal Height Columns with Cross-Browser CSS info is from here: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

you can view and use the solution here:
http://jsbin.com/puvesila/1/edit

update:
I tried without wrappers but I couldn't achieve without them.